# Как можно отправить .mov файл на сервер?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Я получаю видео в `imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])` .

Внутри этого метода я получаю `URL` на `.mov` файл следующим образом:

```swift
guard let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String,
            mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
            let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL else { return }
```

Получаю в итоге `url`:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/B1EF1B3D-5020-48EC-AE66-03FC20357D97/tmp/trim.3C6905E6-7338-48BD-B550-12CC107EEDDE.MOV
```

Как мне можно отправить на сервер этот файл ? Я использую Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от сервера получателя файла.

Я бы получал бы не урл, а видео файл в формате data,
И использовал multipart/form-data его нужно инициализировать в headers и добавить файлы внутри урл реквеста.

let videoMov = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) as! Data

(Код примерный, требуется подогнать под версию)
У alamofire есть классный метод AF.upload поддрерживает пргресс аплоада.